# UIPickerView selectRow won't select last row during initialization

Tags: ios, ios6, uipickerview

I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352166/uipickerview-cant-autoselect-last-row-when-compiled-under-xcode-4-5-2-ios-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114054/uipickerview-selectrowincomponentanimated-not-working-in-viewdidload-but-worki). I have tried the answers to these and other questions found on stackoverflow and Apple's developer forums, with no luck.

I created a fresh project to test this, and it works fine in that new project. I am iteratively removing differences between my new test project and the one exhibiting this issue. Any pointers would be most helpful.

I have a `UIPickerView` connected to my view controller. I want to initialize the `UIPickerView` to the last value selected by the user. However if this row is the last row in the picker, it shows the second-to-last row selected in the UI instead.

Meanwhile, logging shows the correct row index selected in the `UIPickerView` object instance.

Selecting any row besides the last row in the picker works fine.

I have tried calling the `selectRow:inComponent:animated` method from `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear` - none of these make any difference. I have also tried calling `reloadAllComponents` in various orders relative to row selection and data initialization - again, no difference.

Some code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSParameterAssert(self.pickerView);

    // Set pickerView data
    self.pickerOptions = @[@"zero", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four"];

    // Picker View config
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSInteger selectedIndex = ([self.pickerOptions count] -1);
    NSLog(@"About to select row: %d", selectedIndex);
    [self.pickerView selectRow:selectedIndex inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Selected value is %d", [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]);
}

#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSInteger numRows = [self.pickerOptions count];
    NSLog(@"numRows: %d", numRows);
    return numRows;
}

#pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *rowTitle =  [self.pickerOptions objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)row];
    return rowTitle;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *value = [self.pickerOptions objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)row];
    NSLog(@"User selected value: %@", value);
    NSLog(@"index: %d", row);
}
```

Log output:

> -[CCSelectorViewController viewDidAppear:] About to select row index: 4
>   -[CCSelectorViewController pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:] numRows: 5
>   -[CCSelectorViewController viewDidAppear:] Selected row index is 4

Here is the screenshot of the wrong row being selected:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUO1y.jpg

This is using iOS6, XCode 4.6.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you you know that it is second last.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it worked fine for me. Have you done anything to modify the picker view?

Comment: I added a screen shot showing what the picker view UI shows in the simulator, when row with index 4 is selected. Index 4 should be the last row. As you can see, the second-to-last row is selected instead.

Comment: I have not modified the UIPickerView in any way. Sounds like I should try it in a fresh project and see if it still reproduces for me.

Comment: I have also tested this code and is workinf fine.

Comment: I tried this in a fresh project with just a single view, and it worked fine for me also. I guess my next step will be to try making the new project progressively more like my real application, and see if I can replicate the behavior.